# MVC View not passing data to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this view which is not passing data to the controller. Why is this happening?

View:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.threadID)
@Html.ActionLink("Add Post", "CreatePost", "Threads", new { id = Model.threadID })
```

CreatePost Method in Threads Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreatePost(string id)
{
    PostModel model = new PostModel(id);
    return View(model);
}
```

The `DisplayFor` in the view is diplaying the ID (string), however when calling the CreatPost method in the controller, the id being passed is `null`

Comment: Why `string` as an id in the first place...:P? What is the value of `@Model.threadID` in view?

Comment: Oh wait, it could be wrong overload method.

Comment: Show your `PostModel` class.

Comment: Shouldn't it be [HttpPost]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are using wrong overload method, try this one:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Post", "CreatePost", "Threads", new { id = Model.threadID }, null)
```